# A pursuit curve with a constraint

Tags: geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let us consider a surface $\Sigma\subset\mathbb{R}^3$. Given a line $\gamma$ in the ambient space and a point $P\in\Sigma$, we need to find a trajectory of movement of $P$ to pursuit a point on $\gamma$. By saying pursuit I mean that at each moment of time $P$ is getting closer to the given point on $\gamma$ in the sense of the ambient space metric.

A simple algorithm for building such a trajectory is as follows.

Firstly, take $P\in\Sigma$ and connect it with a point $G\in\gamma$. Decompose the vector $PG$ into normal  and tangent components with respect to $\Sigma$ and move a bit by the tangent component on $\Sigma$, thus you're getting a point $P_1\in\Sigma$. Secondly, take a point $G_1\in\gamma$ close to $G$ and, again, decompose $P_1G_1$ into two components, go by the tangent part on $\Sigma$. And so on. Taking the limit of the steps between $G$'s we're getting some curve on a surface.

How would one recommend me making up the differential equations for the coordinates of a point on the surface?